# Swift Quick framework memory leak

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, quick-nimble

I'm using [Quick](https://github.com/quick/quick) to test my Swift code.
However, I think it doesn't release objects defined in `describe` scope:

```swift
class MyClass {
    deinit {
        print(self, #function)
    }
}

final class MyClassSpec: QuickSpec {
    override func spec() {
        describe("") {
            let foo = MyClass()
            it("") {
                print(foo)
                expect(true).to(beTrue())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see any output from `print` inside `deinit`, and a debug breakpoint inside the `deinit` does not get catched.
If I move `foo` inside `it`, the `deinit` is called.

Is this a bug in Quick, or is it normal for `deinit` not to be called in a test suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the code I wrote was not only retaining the object but was also an anti-pattern.

Even a plain old `XCTestCase` retains an object:

```swift
class MyClass {
    deinit {
        print(self, #function)
    }
}

final class MyClassTest: XCTestCase {
    let foo = MyClass()

    func testMyClass() {
        print(foo)
        XCTAssert(true)
    }
}
```

`deinit` is not called for `foo`.

This is due to a nature of `XCTestCase`—[it never really gets `deinit`ed](https://qualitycoding.org/xctestcase-teardown/).
So one should always use `setUp` & `tearDown` to manage *everything* (or more accurately, objects with reference semantics).

I believe this directly translates to `QuickSpec` as well, so I should always use `beforeEach` & `afterEach` in order to manage the objects.
To "fix" the problem, I should test like:

```swift
final class MyClassSpec: QuickSpec {
    override func spec() {
        describe("") {
            let foo: MyClass!

            beforeEach { foo = MyClass() }
            afterEach { foo = nil }

            it("") {
                print(foo)
                expect(true).to(beTrue())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've had exactly the same problem and I've been unable to find many resources on the web relating to memory management in Quick specs.

I've put together a very simple spec to test this out and my own findings seem to mirror yours. It looks like the behaviour does mimic that of XCTest.  So unless anyone else has a better suggestion than implementing `afterEach` for every allocation, I'm going to roll with that 